# Are children allowed in public saunas in Switzerland?

Tags: health, switzerland, children, hot-springs, nudism

I've recently been investigating family-friendly hot spring/spa/sauna options in Switzerland.  Somewhat to my surprise, while most of them permit children into the pool area, all I've found so far -- including [Rigi Kaltbad](https://www.aqua-spa-resorts.ch/en/mineralbad-spa-rigi-kaltbad/about-mineralbad-spa), [Hurlimannbad](https://www.aqua-spa-resorts.ch/en/hurlimannbad-spa-zurich/good-know) (Zurich), and [Vitalis](https://www.alexander-gerbi.ch/en/wellness/wellness_vitalis_spa_multi) (Weggis) -- seem to limit all saunas to 16+ only.  When I emailed one to check, they mentioned a "requirement of legal age" for sauna entry.

**Is this really a Swiss legal requirement?**  And if so, is the rationale health and safety, nudity, or something else?

Comment: I don't believe there's a legal requirement since I recall a sauna in Grisons that allows children when accompanied by adults, but on certain times of certain days only (and limited to families). They might have just used "legal age" to refer to the age of 16/18 in itself.

Comment: A lot of places limit saunas (etc.) to adults, even where everyone is definitely going to be wearing something.  I reckon there are 3 factors: safety worries, wanting to keep them peaceful, and saving the capacity for adults.

Comment: @ChrisH I'd understand if the whole place was off limits to kids, but all three allow children outside the sauna area.

Comment: @lambshaanxy my gym in the UK allows kids in the pool but not the adjacent small sauna, steam room, or hot tub.  I've seen it on the continent too, though I'm a few years out of date there

Comment: I swiftly found many swiss sites giving advice to parents (healthy babies after 4 months ; preferably they can speak and don't need diapers ; since smaller, shorter times and around 50-60°C with no infusion ; Children should never be unsupervised in the sauna)
[(in German) Saunieren mit Kindern | Küng Wellness](https://www.kuengsauna.ch/de/stories/saunieren-mit-kindern). So there doesn't seem to be any **legal requirement**,  more a health and safety until the child has (or thinks they have) learned what works the best for them.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The spas are not banning unattended children, but all children full stop.

Comment: The first 2 belong to **Aqua-Spa-Resorts AG** and seems to be a club requiring membership. (A minimum age of **17 years applies for annual membership**.) For the third I didn't see any age restriction (after a swift read-through).

Comment: The first 2 do have daily prices, but do state **Children may only use the mineral bath & steam bath when accompanied by an adult. No admission for children under the age of 1**. So that seems to be their policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't any national law in Switzerland about this, though it's possible that a canton might have its own laws on the matter.  Otherwise, it's entirely up to the sauna itself.  Rules I've seen include:

- No restrictions at all.
- Restrictions from a certain very low age, e.g. 2+ or 3+, with parent/guardian.
- 14+, 16+, 18+, etc.
- Children only allowed at certain times or on certain days.

You'll have to check the web site of the sauna itself and/or call them to verify.

In my experience, any restrictions appear to be based not on health/safety or state of (un)dress, but rather on the desire of their adult clientele for a peaceful, quiet environment and their opinion about whether that atmosphere will still exist in the presence of children.  I've seen children as young as four or five years old in saunas (with parental supervision, of course).

Indeed, some weeks ago I even saw a family with a practically newborn *baby* in a sauna area in Switzerland.  They didn't take the baby into the actual saunas themselves, but the mother and grandmother took turns watching the baby and visiting the saunas.

All of the above will be the same in Germany and Austria, by the way.